# PHP Undefined index in foreach loop makes no sense

Tags: php, html

This error makes no sense. Here is the code block and my explanation below.

```html
<?php foreach($rows as $value): ?>
                              <?php   echo $value['authorname'] . "<br />\n";?>
                              <?php   echo $value['title'] . "<br />\n";?>
                              <?php   echo $value['rating'] . "<br />\n";?>
                              <?php   echo $value['imagelocation'] . "<br />\n";?>
                    
                            <div class="block">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-8">
                                        <div class="widget-block">
                                            <input id="rate1" value="<?php echo $value['rating'];?>" type="number" class="rating" data-max="5" data-min="0"  data-size="sm" data-show-clear="false" readOnly="readOnly">
                                            <a href="<?php echo $value['sellerssite'];?>" target="#"><img class="img-responsive wow fadeInLeftBig animated" data-wow-duration="1.5s" src=<?php echo $value['$imagelocation'];?> alt=<?php echo $value['$authorname'];?>></a>
                                            <br>
                                            <a href="<?php echo $value['sellerssite'];?>" class="btn btn-success" target="_blank">Buy this book</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-8">
                                        <div class="section-sub-title">
                                            <article class="section-title-body white">
                                                <h1 class="head-title">Author: <span><?php echo $value['$authorname'];?> -</span> <?php echo $value['$title'];?></h1>
                                                <span class="point-line hidden-xs hidden-sm"></span>
                                                <p>
                                                    <?php echo $value['$review'];?>
                                                </p>
                                            </article>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>   
                            </div>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

The echo statements right after the start of the foreach loop prints out each variable fine. It isn't until we get down to the html that there are issues.

This code feeds an array of data from a DB then builds blocks of html code depending on the amount of data. In this case, I am pulling 8 records so this loop creates 8 copies of this code block. The thing that is frustrating is the variable "$rating" injects in all 8 blocks but none of the other variables do even though they print correctly on the page in the echo statements.

Maybe it is the data in the variable? For example as the code is parsed the first variable evaluated is $rating and works. The next one is the src property in the img tag $imagelocation and has an actual value of img\book_covers\TrueConviction.jpg

Are _ and . special characters and causing the issue? My return values would have _ . \ and spaces.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: break tag should be like this echo $value['authorname'] . "</br>\n";?>

Comment: have you tried print_r($rows) and see what it contains.... for that to work, $rows must be an array... all those keys you write must all be present in $value...

Comment: Since rating is correctly outputed, and you generate the 8 code blocks, the fact that the other are not outputed correctly suggests that they are empty. Try var_dump($value) or var_dump($rows) (or print_r as barudo suggested) to see the variable content. My guess is that you either don't select that columns from db, either you select them with other names.

Comment: Thanks for responding however as I stated above ALL the echo statements print the variables returned from the data base. That is why this is so frustrating because I echo print authorname and imagelocation then it's all the sudden empty six code line later? Makes no sense. I feel like the issue is the data IN the variable that is the cause, the characters _ \ . that are part of the string in the variable.

Comment: Typo: `$value['$imagelocation'];` and similar typos found thereafter.  Remove the prefixing $ from your keys.

Comment: Thanks for replying Progrock. That was not an issue. The issue was the special characters IN the data with was solved with urldecode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was right that it was the data IN the variables. The answer was urldecode. This solved my problems. I did this to all my variables.

```
$cleanauthorname = urldecode($value['authorname']);?>
```